# How do you clear a twitter session in Rails 3 app using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, devise, omniauth, logout

I am using the devise, omniauth, omniauth-twitter and twitter gems in a rails 3 app. I want to make it so when a user signs out it also removes the twitter gem configuration. What I'm referring to when I say "twitter gem configuration" is this:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

If I don't do that and another user logs onto the app from the same computer but doesn't have a user account, they will see the previous user's twitter information. I believe I can remove the configuration by calling

```
Twitter.reset
```

I guess my question is where would be the best place to put that? Also if that isn't the best way to remove the user's twitter configuration, how should I do it?

Thanks and let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working.

In `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` you can redirect the default route devise sends the user when they sign_in/out. I'm not sure if this is the "proper" place to put this but it seems reasonable.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if current_user.authentications.find_by_provider("twitter")
      ckey= YOUR_APPS_CONSUMER_KEY
      csecret= YOUR_APPS_CONSUMER_SECRET
      auth = current_user.authentications.find_by_provider("twitter")
      atoken = auth.token
      asecret = auth.secret
      Twitter.configure do |config|
        config.consumer_key = ckey
        config.consumer_secret = csecret
        config.oauth_token = atoken
        config.oauth_token_secret = asecret
      end
    end

    authentications_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
      Twitter.reset
      authentications_path
  end


end
```

The `authentications_path` is just the page I'm using to test the authentications and related things. You can redirect anywhere. When a user links an account I save their oauth token and secret in the authentication object. You will need this to access certain aspects of the Twitter gem.

I'll wait a little while to mark this as the answer, see if someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your configuration into application-specific (which will be global) and client-specific settings. [This twitter gem wiki page](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/wiki/Configuration) describes this nicely.

Comment: As I understand it, whatever user's token and secret I put into config.oauth_token and config.oauth_token_secret determine's who's home_timeline I am accessing? I believe this config is actually a combination of the app credentials and the specific user's credentials.

Comment: You are right. Some of your configuration is per client. I have updated my reply accordingly.

Comment: OK, that was informative, I'll split those two things up. But I'm still wondering what part of the rails app is the "correct" place to put the code to clear the specific user's oauth credentials when the user signs out?

Comment: Generally, you will create a separate SessionController/AuthorizationController for the "user session". When user signs in, you create this resouurce and when he logs out, you destroy this resource.